# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when breaking file up

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that takes a file with a company's name and phone number and splits it up into name, area code, and phone number.  My problem is that whenever i try running the program i get the error segmentation fault (core dumped).  I've tried using malloc with my pointers but it didn't seem to work.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>
typedef struct {
    char name[30];
    char areacode[10];
    char phone[14];
} phone_numbers;

int ReadNumber(phone_numbers *phone) {

    FILE *input = fopen("phone_numbers.txt", "r");

    char length[200];
    char *temp;
    int i;

    if (input == NULL) {

         printf("File can not open");
    }
    while (fgets(length, sizeof(length), input) != NULL) {
        temp = strtok(length, " ");
        strcpy(phone[i].name, temp);

        temp = strtok(NULL, "-");
        strcpy(phone[i].areacode, temp);

        temp = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        strcpy(phone[i].phone, temp);

        i++;
    }
    fclose(input);
    return i;
}



void PrintNumbers (phone_numbers *phone, int i) {
    int j;

    for(j=0; j <= i; j++) {

        printf("Business: %s Area code: %s Phone: %s \n", phone[i].name, phone[i].areacode, phone[i].phone);
    }
    return;
}

int main() {

    phone_numbers phone[10];
    int i;

    i = ReadNumber(phone);

    PrintNumbers(phone, i);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might start with checking to make sure `strtok` did not return a null pointer.

Comment: If you turn on `-Wall -Wextra` flags in GCC or Clang (or similar warning flags in other compilers), you will be prompted to initialize `i` in `ReadNumber` function.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is that you didn't initialize `i` in your `ReadNumber()` function.

Also, you should always check whether `strtok()` is returning `NULL`.